# Hide/Disable Text from Date Picker Dialog in android

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using Date Picker Dialog in my android app.I want to hide text show on top of date picker dialog.Can i hide/disable text from date picker dialog.Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

use this one

```
DatePickerDialog dialog= new DatePickerDialog(this, dateSetListener, year, month, day);
                  dialog.setTitle("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [setTitle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method.